# Does the address translation of paging decrease memory access performance?

Tags: cpu, paging, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, mmu

When paging is enabled, some hardware is responsible for translating virtual memory addresses into physical addresses. Known translations are usually kept in some sort of cache, the translation look aside buffer (TLB).

**Assuming a memory access where the address translation is cached, is it any slower than directly accessing memory without paging enabled?**

I'm wondering about the overhead of that translation, even when it's cached, since the access to that cache will probably also take some (although very short) time. Or is that time planned as part of the clock cycle?

(To make it clear, my question is not about page faults or cache misses of the TLB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like everything in life, it depends! :-)

Let's assume, for the sake of simplicity, that (a) we're talking about data rather than instructions (b) all data memory accesses hit the level 1 cache (c) the level 1 data cache is a typical set associative cache.

Each block of the  data cache must be identified with an address (less the offset). If the cache uses virtual addresses then no translation need take place and there is no overhead. If the cache uses physical addresses then the address must be translated prior to the data access adding additional latency to the request. Even for a small TLB, I don't think a high performance processor could both translate the address and then complete the cache request within the same cycle. So it's fair to assume that a physically addressed cache does indeed have overhead of address translation.

So virtually addressed caches sound like the better deal, right? Unfortunately it's a double-edged sword. The problem is that virtual memory often allows multiple virtual addresses to map to the same physical address. If in our cache there are two virtual addresses that map to a single physical address, modifying one will not be reflected in the other.

So, there is an option between these two extremes. Still assuming a set associative cache, we can use the virtual address as the index while simultaneously translating the address to a physical one. After, we use the physical address as the tag to access the data. This way we take the TLB translation off the critical path thus achieving similar performance to the virtually addressed cache. It also allows us to avoid this virtual/physical aliasing problem, although it often needs a little extra help from the operating system.

So, you can see that it can be the same or slower, depending on how the cache is configured.

Comment: Awesome. Do you know how it is implemented in "common" CPUs like some recent Intel or AMD desktop processor?

Comment: @DanielJour According to the 5th edition of Hennessy & Patterson, the Intel i7 (which in 2011 should have been a Nehalem/Westmere) the level-1 cache is virtually indexed-physically tagged whereas the level-2 and level-3 caches are physically tagged. I found a few other reference online that suggest that Intel's Sandy Bridge is also virtually indexed-physically tagged. I would imagine it's still true for Haswell and Skylake.

Comment: Perfect. I actually have that book (well, the 4th edition, which contains a case study of some AMD chip) here :)